# « Se perfectionner soi-même », pléonasme ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

Est-ce que les expressions « se perfectionner soi-même », « se perfectionner » et « perfectionner soi-même » sont équivalentes ?

Je m'explique : par souci d'uniformité (titres de chapitre), la formulation « perfectionner soi-même » est celle que je souhaite employer. Or, en cherchant cette expression sur Internet, c'est « se perfectionner soi-même » qui revient systématiquement, mais elle me semble être un pléonasme.

Comment: Les deux n'ont pas le même sens. *Se perfectionner* c'est s'améliorer, progresser.  *Se perfectionner soi-même* évoque un travail intérieur, sur soi (je pense à Confucius qui parle de se « perfectionner soi-même », mais pas que).  À mon avis il faut aussi différencier *se perfectionner soi-même*  de *se perfectionner tout seul*, ce qui voudrait dire sans l'aide d'un quelconque moyen extérieur. Si tu donnes un contexte, ce sera peut-être plus facile de te répondre.

Comment: « Se perfectionner » [comment ?]  || « Se perfectionner » [en quoi ?] || « Se perfectionner » [par quel moyen ?] →  qui fait quoi sur qui ou quoi ? → *Se perfectionner [**par**] soi-même*

Comment: Comme le dit cette [source](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-reflechis), *On emploie le pronom réfléchi avec les verbes pronominaux dans le sens de « soi-même »*.  Donc, "se perfectionner soi-même" est  un pléonasme (une redondance pour les plus tolérants). "perfectionner soi-même" sonne plutôt mal.

Comment: @Graffito … "se perfectionner soi-même" est peut-être un *pléonasme* grammaticalement, mais pas logiquement, le supprimer amène un problème d'oreille, comme vous le notez. [Se = ] Soi-même perfectionne soi-même … et personne d'autre ne peut le faire. La logique sous-jacente est victime, soit de l'élision du [par], soit de la transformation du mot composé ‘soi-même’ en *se*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je ne pourrais pas expliquer pourquoi, mais effectivement, il semble manquer quelque chose dans *perfectionner soi-même*, c'est un peu bancal s'il n'y a rien d'autre dans la phrase. Si on remplace *soi-même* par *son caractère* pour donner: *perfectionner son caractère*, tout va bien, et en fait, on ne dirait pas *se perfectionner son caractère*.

Dans *perfectionner soi-même *quelque chose**, le sens est que l'on est engagé dans un processus de perfectionnement sans l'aide d'un autre. Mais il faut ajouter un COD pour préciser ce que l'on perfectionne.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord (mais je n'ai pas moinssoyé!). Je pense qu'il faut creuser la différence  - ou pas - entre soi-même et tout seul. C'est flou dans ma tête et je n'ai pas de réponse.

Comment: @None Oui, mais la question est plutôt sur le _se_, non? Je n'ai pas pensé à _tout seul_ car ce n'était pas mentionné dans la question.

Comment: D'où ma demande de précision au PO. Je trouvais que la question avait besoin d'être améliorée... le contexte, le contexte... on ne le dira jamais assez quand les gens posent des questions.

Comment: @None - Mais quel aspect de ma réponse te chagrine? (tu as dit que tu n'étais pas d'accord)

Comment: "il semble manquer quelque chose dans perfectionner soi-même" ben, tout dépend (contexte).

Comment: @None je vois - je viens d'ajouter des détails.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. @None Le contexte est en effet confucéen.

Comment: @FirminMartin Ah ! Il aurait fallu le mettre dans la question ! « Se perfectionner soi-même » étant un concept propre à la philosophie confucéenne (et ça se dit comme ça en français, je ne connais pas le chinois de toutes façon !) c'est important de le laisser tel que c'est exprimé habituellement.